Docker cant create my tables with Alembic (or maybe its something with SQLAlchemy)
When I try to run my program not in Docker, everything is OK, but when I try to docker-compose up --build with Docker, I get the error sqlalchemy.exc.MissingGreenlet: greenlet_spawn has not been called; can't call await_only() here. Was IO attempted in an unexpected place? (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/xd2s)
Actually, i dont know what to do :(
Here is my code:
env.py
import asyncio
from logging.config import fileConfig

from sqlalchemy import pool
from sqlalchemy.engine import Connection
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import async_engine_from_config

from alembic import context

from models import *
from config.settings import get_settings

config = context.config


config.set_section_option(
    config.config_ini_section, "sqlalchemy.url", get_settings().asyncpg_url
)


if config.config_file_name is not None:
    fileConfig(config.config_file_name)

target_metadata = Base.metadata



def run_migrations_offline() -> None:
    """Run migrations in 'offline' mode.

    This configures the context with just a URL
    and not an Engine, though an Engine is acceptable
    here as well.  By skipping the Engine creation
    we don't even need a DBAPI to be available.

    Calls to context.execute() here emit the given string to the
    script output.

    """
    url = get_settings().asyncpg_url
    context.configure(
        url=url,
        target_metadata=target_metadata,
        literal_binds=True,
        dialect_opts={"paramstyle": "named"},
    )

    with context.begin_transaction():
        context.run_migrations()


def do_run_migrations(connection: Connection) -> None:
    context.configure(connection=connection, target_metadata=target_metadata)

    with context.begin_transaction():
        context.run_migrations()


async def run_async_migrations() -> None:
    """In this scenario we need to create an Engine
    and associate a connection with the context.

    """

    connectable = async_engine_from_config(
        config.get_section(config.config_ini_section, {}),
        prefix="sqlalchemy.",
        poolclass=pool.NullPool,
    )

    async with connectable.connect() as connection:
        await connection.run_sync(do_run_migrations)

    await connectable.dispose()


def run_migrations_online() -> None:
    """Run migrations in 'online' mode."""

    asyncio.run(run_async_migrations())


if context.is_offline_mode():
    run_migrations_offline()
else:
    run_migrations_online()

docker-compose
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: 'postgres:16'
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U postgres"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    volumes:
      - './pgsql:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
    networks:
      - default

  backend:
    container_name: backend
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "3000:80"
    links:
      - postgres
    depends_on:
      postgres:
        condition: service_healthy
    networks:
      - default

networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  pgsql:
    driver: local
    enter code here

Dockerfile
FROM python:3.10

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./requirements.txt ./requirements.txt

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /app/requirements.txt

COPY . .

RUN if [ ! -d "/app/migrations" ]; then alembic init migrations; fi

RUN chmod 755 /app/start.sh

CMD ["sh", "start.sh"]

start.sh
#!/bin/sh
if [ ! -d "/app/migrations" ]; then
    alembic init migrations
fi

alembic upgrade head
uvicorn app.main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 80


Try using alembic init --template async migrations

@GordThompson it seems like they are using the async template already? the env.py file has async code in it

@python_user is right. I have already has the async template in env.py. So i dont know what is the problem

on a second read, I think @GordThompson was referring to your docker file and start.sh where you don't use async templates

@python_user I tried to put it in start.sh and dockerfile. This error doesnt occur anymore. But i got another problem:
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

can you show the connection string you are using

@python_user https://github.com/Trinadtsatiy/TodoingAPI/blob/todoing_Dev/app/config/settings.py#L26C5-L28C145

can you show the hardcoded values? username and password aside

@python_user what do mean as hardcore values?

substitute the env values, I want to see what you use as the hostname

@python_user
POSTGRES_USER=postgres
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
POSTGRES_HOST=localhost
POSTGRES_PORT=5432
POSTGRES_DB=postgres
But i think i got the main problem. I think the start.sh creates migrations folder but do not configurate it.

I have the feeling the main problem is not technical, but that you have 3+ projects interact, and you don't understand all of them well enough to get them working together.
If you agree, I want you to know that it is possible to learn all of it! You just need to take smaller steps.
I recommend to work in the following order. In the end you will understand enough to make it work without our help.
1. Manual Postgres
Install Postgres manually and connect to it via a GUI tool like PGAdmin or the shell client postgresql.

[ ] Create a table
[ ] insert 3 data entries
[ ] list all data entries
[ ] then delete the table

If you run into errors, feel free to ask stackoverflow again, and also feel free to mention me in a comment.
2. Postgres Docker Container
Now try to build your own docker image that contains postgres and run the container. Try to connect to it again and repeat the previous exercises. They are now your tests.
3. SQLAlchemy
Now write a Python script with SQLAlchemy to do your exercises. Think about where you can check for errors and create corresponding error messages.
Start the container again and see if it works.
This is also a great point to learn about Exceptions and stack traces.
4. SQLAlchemy Container
Now create a docker image that contains your Python script. With docker-compose make sure that both containers start by themselves, and see if the logs of the docker container show that the tests worked correctly.
If the logs don't show much, think about how to optimize your Python script for that usecase. If you work in docker containers this will be your main way to see if something is healthy.
5. Add Alembic to your Python script
Now get back to your Alembic tutorial and adapt your Python script so it starts Alembic correctly.
How could a "hello world" test could look like with Alembic that is similar in spirit to the SQLAlchemy one?
6. Rinse and Repeat
Especially if you are new to Python or coding in general, it would make sense to restart this whole exercise once you finished. This way you can connect the dots between your first and last exercises, while also memorizing more of the activities.
Enjoy learning.
